# having trouble implementing AbstractTocProvider in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tableofcontents

I used the following link to implement AbstractTocProvider
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-ua/documents/providers_api.html
but it is not appearing in the help->help contents
Can you tell me what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is the `getTocContributions` method being called? If not is the `tocProvider` in the plugin.xml correct?

Comment: @greg-449 yes plugin.xml is proper ! There were some unimplemented methods in the class, i added i. Now when i run as eclipse application and do help->help contents the tocProvider class is not run i thin, because the print statement i have given is not printed ! well the statement is never printed!